# WS-Federation / Windows Authentication / AD / ADFS

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, windows-authentication, ws-federation

I'm having difficulty understanding the concepts of WS-Federation and distinguishing it
from Windows Authentication. If I want to log in using Active Directory, can I opt for Windows Authentication or WS-Federation? Furthermore, when it comes to ADFS, which option should I choose?